# Ich spreche keines

Tags: colloquial

Ist die Antwort korrekt und klingt sie gebräuchlich? Würden Sie *keines* oder *keins* sagen? Soweit ich weiß, ist beides korrekt.

> Sprichst du Deutsch?
> Nein, ich spreche keines/keins.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nein, denn *keines* oder *keins* ohne ein Nomen setzt Wahlmöglichkeiten voraus. Ein Synonym ist *nichts davon*.

> Gras? Pillen? — Keines bitte.
>
> Gras? Pillen? — Nichts davon bitte.

Aber bei

> Sprichst du Deutsch?

geht es um eine ja/nein-Frage. Solche Fragen kann man nicht mit *keines* beantworten. Stattdessen einfach:

> Nein.

> Leider nicht.

> Nicht so gut.

Oder ähnlich.

Answer (score 3):

Weder noch, das würde ich in Bezug auf Sprachen nie so nutzen. Meine Antwort wäre

> Nein, das spreche/kann ich nicht.
> Nein, ich spreche/kann kein Deutsch.

Comment: Mit dem letzten Satz kann ich mich nicht anfreunden. Formulierungen wie "Ich habe keine.", "Ich möchte keines.", "Ich kenne keinen." etc. (natürlich, wenn aus dem Kontext hervorgeht, worum es geht) scheinen mir allgegenwärtig.

Comment: Ich fürchte, du hast recht. Janka hat es gut getroffen

Answer (score 2):

Das standarddeutsche Wort ist *»keines«.* Die Version ohne *e* in der Endsilbe (*»keins«*) ist umgangssprachlich und wird (bis auf sehr wenige Ausnahmen) nur in gesprochenem Deutsch verwendet. Wenn Deutsch geschrieben wird, wird nur sehr selten *»keins«* verwendet, und wenn doch, dann meist um gesprochenes Deutsch in schriftlicher Form wiederzugeben (z.B. direkte und indirekte Rede und auch in Erzählungen, bei denen durch die Annäherung an das gesprochene Deutsch mehr Lebendigkeit vermittelt werden soll).

Der Grund dafür, dass es überhaupt zwei Versionen dieses Wortes gibt, ist, dass schon seit Jahrhunderten das *e* aus den Endsilben vieler Wörter verschwindet, und die Wörter *»keines, eines, seines, meines, ihres, ...«* gehören zu den Wörtern, bei denen das passiert. Dieser Vorgang ist bei verschiedenen Wörtern unterschiedlich weit fortgeschritten. (Bei *derbe/derb* und *blöde/blöd* ist die Form mit *e* so gut wie völlig ungebräuchlich, bei *rüde/rüd* und *leise/leis* ist das Verschwinden des *e* noch nicht weit fortgeschritten.) Interessant ist auch, dass aus *»unseres«* und *»eueres«* das *e* aus der mittleren Silbe verschwindet bzw. schon verschwunden ist (*»unsres«, »eures«*).

---

Die Konstruktion der Antwort ist übrigens eigentlich grammatisch völlig korrekt, was man leicht erkennt, wenn man sich ähnliche Beispiele ansieht:

> Möchtest du ein Steak? - Nein, ich möchte keines.
> Kennst du ein böses Weib? - Nein, ich kenne keines.

Dabei ist auch egal, ob das, worauf sich *»keines«* bezieht, zählbar oder unzählbar ist:

> Hast du Geld? - Nein, ich habe keines.
> Hast du ein Auto? - Nein, ich habe keines.

Wenn diese Antworten nicht geschrieben, sondern gesprochen werden, darf man *»keines«* gerne/gern durch *»keins«* ersetzten. Im geschriebenen Deutsch sollte man besser bei *»keines«* bleiben.

### Aber Vorsicht!

Diese Konstruktion ist nicht mit allen Substantiven kompatibel, insbesondere wird diese Konstruktion niemals von deutschen Muttersprachlern verwendet, wenn es um Sprachen geht:

- Frage:

  > Sprichst du Japanisch?
- Das ist sehr ungebräuchlich und sollte daher nicht eingelernt werden:

  > Nein, ich spreche keines.
  > Nein, ich spreche keins.

  Wer das sagt, wird zwar verstanden, gibt sich aber gleichzeitig auch sofort als Nicht-Muttersprachler zu erkennen.
- Das sagen Muttersprachler:

  > Nein.
  > Nein, ich spreche kein Japanisch.

  Das ist richtiges und gutes Deutsch.

Comment: Warum soll *(k)eins* umgangssprachlich sein? Man findet sehr viele Zeitungs- und Buchbelege: *es ist ein Parisbuch, wie es noch keins gab* (Zeit), *so daß keins der zahlreichen geistlichen und weltlichen Verbote nachhaltige Wirkung hatte* (Meyers Großes Konversations-Lexikon).

Comment: @DavidVogt: Man findet aber erheblich mehr Belege mit e.

Comment: Du erwähnst es eh im vorletzten Beispiel, aber ich möchte nochmal hervorheben: auch nur ein alleinstehendes _Nein_ ist eine völlig akteptable Antwort (was ja für das Englische oft bestritten wird).

Comment: Selten und umgangssprachlich sind verschiedene Dimensionen.

Comment: @DavidVogt: Stimmt. Aber was genau ist dann dein Argument? Ich dachte, du wolltest durch den Verweis auf zwei Belege veranschaulichen, dass *»keins«* nicht umgangssprachlich sein könne. Ich habe ja im ersten Absatz ausdrücklich erwähnt, dass diese Form des Wortes in bestimmten Situationen auch in der Schriftform auftauchen kann. Und nichts anders belegt dein Kommentar.

Comment: Ich verstehe nicht, worauf sich die Wertung als umgangssprachlich stützt. Nur darauf, daß das eine häufiger ist? Das ist nicht hinreichend. Die Belege sind zu zahlreich, um als Fehler oder Ausrutscher zu gelten. Wenn die Form in Zeitungen und Büchern etabliert (aber selten) ist, kann es sich nicht um Umgangssprache handeln. Im [DWDS-Zeitungskorpus](https://www.dwds.de/d/korpora/public) steht es z.B. im Kontext *kein(e)s von beidem* 38:22 für die Form mit *e*, im Kontext *kein(e)s da* 36:43. Wieso mache ich mir eigentlich diese Arbeit und nicht derjenige, der die Behauptung aufgestellt hat?